# c++: inheritance and templates performance trade offs

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Yesterday, I was asked a question, what are the performance trade offs between using inheritance and templates?

I said in case of virtual functions, the dynamic linkage will cause some performance problem when it comes to inheritance. However, with templates, the specialized classes will be generated during compile time itself, so there is no performance problem except the size of the executable grows along with the number of specialized classes.

Can anyone explain if there are other things to consider here?

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: Dunno if "dynamic linkage" is the usual term for what virtual functions do...course i've never heard the word "linkage" used outside the context of static vs dynamic libraries and object files, so eh...

Comment: The correct terminology for "dynamic linkage" is dynamic binding or [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch), if I understand correctly what you are describing

Comment: @amit you're right - you can check the terminology here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

Comment: yes... dynamic binding is a more common term.

Comment: This sounds like yet another interview question where the interviewer didn't completely understand what he was asking.

Comment: Templates and inheritance are different things. You can't just compare them like that. Use the one that models your problem.

Comment: @rahul - The fastest program is the one without any code at all. Runs in no time flat, and has absolutely no overhead.

Comment: You, certainly, can compare "theoretical" pros and cons of performance of a program doing the same thing using virtual functions or templates. The "other things to consider" can be - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)#Advantages_and_disadvantages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all - inheritance & templates are - in my point of view - orthogonal to each other (see OOSC for a chapter on that). In C++ the trade-offs basically boil down to:

- Templates require space in the executable because each specialization
  requires code to be generated.
- Inheritance with virtual functions require a vtable, all non-static method calls require one additional parameter (this) and calls to virtual functions have on indirection via the vtable.

So it's space vs. speed. But you can have the benefits & drawbacks of both in the same class (see my first sentence - the features are orthogonal in what they want to reach).

Comment: yes.. that's pretty much what I told the guy. but he wasn't too impressed. Thats why I just wanted to know if performance thing comes into picture when we talk about templates.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite correct in saying that virtual functions can have a performance overhead and template instantiation has a code size overhead, but both can be mitigated.

I keep having to remind myself that C++ is built on the premise of not paying for what you don't use, so with inherited classes you can always move common code into a non-virtual function to avoid a vtable lookup, and sometimes making a method inline can play well with the compiler's optimisation and make the code faster (no function call) *and* smaller.

Similarly with templates, any code which does not rely on the templated types can be pushed up into a non-template base class and therefore there will only be one copy of the function.